# I'am calling same javascript file from two different locations.Its working on one but not on another call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]Actually, I am trying two appends the list in the  tag by calling javascript file.I am using this code in modal files first call is working correctly but when I try to call from second location call is not working.

Code:-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="list"><?php _e('Add List'); ?></label>
    <ul class="" >
        <?php $milestonearray = array(); $milestonearray = unserialize($milestone['lists']);
              foreach($milestonearray as $milestones){
        ?>
        <li><input type='checkbox' name='milestone[]' value='<?php echo $milestones ?>' checked><span class='text'><?php echo $milestones ?></span></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="box-footer">
          <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" id="listname" name="listname"  placeholder="Type name...">

            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" id='x' class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Javascript call:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#x').click(function(){   
  var new_task = document.getElementById("listname").value;

    if(new_task!= ""){
        $('.todo-list').append("<li><input type='checkbox' 
        name='milestone[]' value='"+new_task+"' checked><span 
        class='text'>"+new_task+"</li>");

        $('#listname').val('');
    }   
});
```

I am including the jquery in the header.Also when trying to alert the value it alerting null.

First call-:
Second call:-

Comment: This is not 100% clear explanation what you trying to do.

Comment: I want to to add the <li> element by clicking on button

Comment: You don't state whether the html is loaded dynamically: In front of `$('#x').click(function()` add `console.log($(#x").length)` - if it's zero in the console then you're loading your content *after* the script runs and so has nothing to wire the click event to - you need to use event delegation.